# a loop that prints all the items (no matter how long the chain is) *pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The following is a basic code and I was wondering what was the basic way to write a loop on how to display the contents/data from the array of pointers. The top is a class with everything under public. Declaring a data of string followed by an array of pointers called next. In the main function, I'm declaring a few nodes and allocating memory to its followed by a string. A, B, and C. Towards the end of the code I'm connecting the pointers to each data and the last one C to NULL. And at the end, I'm having a bit of trouble writing or grasping the concept on how to write a loop to display it's contents, i.e Node1, Node2, Node3... Preferably a loop that'll display everything no matter the size.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    string data;
    node * next;
};


int main()
{

    node * A;
    A = new node;
    (*A).data = "node1";


    node * B;
    B = new node;
    (*B).data = "node2";

    node * C;
    C = new node;
    (*C).data = "node3";

    (*A).next = B;
    (*B).next = C;
    (*C).next = NULL;

    for(int i=0; *(next) != NULL; i++)
    {
        cout << *next[i[] << endl;
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Try to make it a [mcve] and I'm pretty sure you'll have the keys for a resolution.

Comment: it doesn't compile due to the for loop.. which is the reason for this post.

Comment: I'll stick to @Sunil resolution then. No need here for a for-loop, a while is much more appropriate due to the data type you handle.

Answer (score 0):

use a temporary pointer that's initialized with the start of the node and use a `while` loop.

```
Node* tmp = A;
while (tmp) {   // same as (tmp != NULL)
  cout << tmp->data << endl;
  tmp = tmp->next;   // down the rabbit hole
}
```

Also, You could collapse the declaration of variables with assignment.

`Node* A = new Node;`

Answer (score 0):

1.) remove for loop

```
printList(A);

void printList(node *first)
{
   node *first = A;
   while(first)
   {
   cout<<first->data<<endl;
   }
}
```